# Recursive ajax() requests

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, recursion

I use jQuery's `ajax()`to get information. I call the method when the request is successful. Here is the code:

```
function recursively_ajax(){
    console.warn("begin");
    $.ajax({
        type:"GET",
        url: "./JvmInfoClass",
        success: function(data){
            console.warn("get jvm info success");
            recursively_ajax();
        }
    });
}

recursively_ajax();
```

I make the thread sleep 3 seconds in the back-end. But the console print the message continuously not after 3 seconds. Why is this?

Comment: Try `if(data){ console.log(); }` and also share server-side code.

Comment: Is your server caching the response and returning it immediately after the first one? i.e. is there a 3 second delay the very first time after clearing your browser cache.

Comment: Spot on. The problem has been resolved. Many thanks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can try this with ajax call async:false

```
var counter=0;
 function recursively_ajax()
{
var pass_data=5;
var chartMenu=['VTR','NC','RC','TOCU','TOCO','TR','COA','MP'];
$.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        async:false, // set async false to wait for previous response
        url: "url to server",
        dataType:"json",
        data:{dataMenu:pass_data},
        success: function(data)
        {
            counter++;
            if(counter < chartMenu.length){
                recursively_ajax();
            }
        }
    });
 }      
 recursively_ajax();
```

Comment: @Always Sunny Can you tell me for a large array size(for example for 70 ) the order of ajax responses will be same as array order using your method ?Thanks

Comment: `async: false`, may freeze the UI.

Answer (score 12):

in that case the bug is in the server side code because the server should sent back the response only after 3 seconds.

But I would recommend to use `setTimeout()` in the client side to restrict the request frequency

Try

```
function recursively_ajax(){
    console.warn("begin");
    $.ajax({
        type:"GET",
        url: "./JvmInfoClass",
        success: function(data){
            console.warn("get jvm info success");
            setTimeout(recursively_ajax, 3000)
        }
    });
}
recursively_ajax();
```

Answer (score 4):

It's browser's cacheing problem,I append the date to the url or set the ajax cache:false,the problem is solved.Thank everyone.